# Translating XML templates in Django

Tags: python, xml, django

I am using Django 1.9 and have a XML template in the application's `template` folder, like this:

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "http://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml.dtd">
<document filename="testdocument.pdf" colorSpace="CMYK" author="Me" title="Report">
...
```

I am placing `{% trans "Foo" %}` markers as usual, but `makemessages -l <lang>` doesn't create them in the .po file. HTML templates work fine.

How can I translate XML templates?

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed it with `makemessages -l <lang> -e xml`

Comment: Why is this a LQP?  This is fine!